# getElementsByClassName but manipulate only the one that i want

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

i have multiple div with same classname but i want to change only one of their opacity, the one that i interact with a mouse or touch. How can i do it? The below code changing all of theirs properties, apparently.  Full .js code is here if anyone would like to take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/b7y6mfv4/

```
var target1 = document.getElementsByClassName('beforeLabel');
var target2 = document.getElementsByClassName('afterLabel');

        for (var i=0; i<target1.length; i++) {
    target1[i].style.opacity = beforeAfter;
    target2[i].style.opacity = beforeAfter2;
}
```

Comment: It'd be better if you provided an actually usable fiddle (and with accompanying HTML). Also, there's no need to upload it to JSFiddle - you can use Stack Overflow's own fiddle sandbox (it's essentially JSFiddle, but contained within your question). Just press `Ctrl + M` to add a fiddle anywhere in your question.

Comment: You are absolutely right about accommpanying html, i put it here: https://jsfiddle.net/qtaf723s/  and i will do it on stackoverflow next time because i didnt know it.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, change `document.getElementsByClassName` to `evt.target.getElementsByClassName` and get rid of the loop.

Target lets you reference only the element that is the target of the event.

Comment: thank you. But if i do it, then it changes the container div's opacity. ( evt.target.style.opacity = beforeAfter2;) How can i change the div that inside with a class name 'beforeLabel' and 'afterLabel.'?

Comment: @studentUmit I updated my answer. Instead of referring to `document` which searches the entire document, you can replace it with `evt.target` and it will search the children of that element.

Comment: then the class opacity is not affected? Nothing chaning?
'''
  var target1 = evt.target.getElementsByClassName('beforeLabel');
  var target2 = evt.target.getElementsByClassName('afterLabel');

 
     target1.opacity = beforeAfter;
  target2.opacity = beforeAfter2;
'''

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is looping through all elements with either of those two class names and applying opacity. What you can do is make use of the mouse events target property, which will give you the specific element which has been interacted with, and apply the opacity to that.

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
  if (event.target.className.includes("beforeLabel")) {
    event.target.style.opacity = 0.5;
  }
});
```

You can see a full working example [here](https://codepen.io/NoPantsPirate/pen/xxwNBRv).

Comment: Hi Ryan, did you see this code? https://jsfiddle.net/ez7x52Lr/
I want to reach a child div.